Restructure OOP Architecture for two classes that are currently circular dependent
I'm working on a simple 2D game using C++ and SFML.
In this game, I have a class WorkbenchBlock which inherits from class Block. The block class handles everything to do with how the block is rendered in the world, as well as collision information. WorkbenchBlock extends off of that by adding some specific methods such as on_use().
I also have another class WorkbenchItem which inherits from InventoryItem. The InventoryItem class handles everything to do with how this item appears in the player's inventory, as well its stack size.
Now here is my main question. My initial plan was to add a method to WorkbenchItem to return a new WorkbenchBlock(//parameters). This would be called when the player attempts to place the Item, and a Block-representation of that item is needed. Likewise WorkbenchBlock would also have a function that returns a new WorkbenchItem(//parameters). This method would be called when the block is broken, and an item representation of the block is needed.
However, this introduces the problem of circular dependencies: WorkbenchItem requires WorkbenchBlock, and WorkbenchBlock requires WorkbenchItem.
So, I have come to the conclusion that the architecture for these two classes needs to change, but I am not sure a good way to go about that.
I have considered having the methods return an Enum instead of a new class that can be passed into another function to finally return the new class, but not sure that would fit my use cases as it could get pretty complicated and hard to manage when extra parameters are needed when I create a new instance of the class.
Is there another OOP approach to solve this problem and restructure my code?
Thanks.

Favour composition over inheritance.  This is especially true in games architecture where deep inheritance hierarchies are runtime inflexible due to being defined at compile-time, and have hidden maintenance (fragile base class problem) and performance (vtables) costs. This should also solve circular dependencies.
